# Laravel not generating session. Redirects with meta tags just after auth success

Tags: php, session, redirect, laravel

hey guys i am in big confusion as my project is not working on some machines.

I have an UserController which is responsible to call Auth::attempt() for login and on successful login it should redirect to admin page.

But on some machines it redirects (just after auth::attemp() success) to admin page but with meta tags and session not created at all! And then again back to login page(by filter).

I have checked twice(even views file) but no one is sending headers before redirect.

This is happening on few machines not all.

```
public function adminLogin()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get( 'email' ),'password' => Input::get('password'))) && Auth::user()->power == 1)
        {
            return Redirect::intended('admin');
        }
    else
        {
            Auth::logout();
            return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors( 'Entered details are invalid or You may not have Admin Power' );
        }
}
```

This is my function on UserController.php responsible for login.
Also one more thing if i entered wrong login details on login page. Then again it says Redirecting ..to ... message but error is shown. So thing is to note that session are working because i am still getting errors message through

```
@if (Session::has('errors'))
    $("#output").addClass("alert alert-danger animated fadeInUp").html('{{ $errors->all()[0]   }}'); 
@endif
```

and this shows error when there is wrong login details entered. So i guess there is something session handling. May be something wrong with specific hosts?

Comment: What do you mean "on some machines"? You mean on user PCs? Have you checked if cookies are enabled in browser you tested it?

Comment: I mean on some web hosts

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `storage` directory (and subdirectories, especially `sessions`)  have enough permission. On some web hosts you may need to set them to for example `0755` or even `0777` depending on web host configuration.

Comment: all chmod are correct even tried to set them 0777 but still no success. However i noticed that laravel is creating session files there in storage/session

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `storage` directory being set with the correct file read/write/execute permissions (`chmod`). You also need to ensure that it is writable by the webserver using `chown`. If you are using apache then ensure that the apache user and group own the storage directory and all of the subdirectories and files.

`chown -R apache:apache storage`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there are blank lines before the opening flash('message,'My error message'); in my web form page.

Check the following page:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-suddenly-displays-redirecting-page

I know the OP said that they checked for this but it may help others.